# Solving an equation of two variables by looping over different values for one variable

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I have a function: `f[x_,y_]=x+y`. I would like to loop over some values of `x`, and solve for `y` accordingly. I tried using a loop:

```
Do[Solve[f[x, y] == 0, {y}], {x, 5}]
```

but it does not print anything out. What am I missing?

Comment: `Table`  instead of `Do`.

Comment: `Reap[Do[Sow[Solve[f[x, y] == 0, {y}]], {x, 5}]]`

Comment: You are actually doing what you want, the issue is that you are not returning the values. Add `Print@` in front of `Solve` to understand what I mean. Using `Table` as recommended by _march_ is one simple way to overcome this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any loop:

```
 Solve[f[#, y] == 0, {y}] & /@ Range[5]
 {{{y -> -1}}, {{y -> -2}}, {{y -> -3}}, {{y -> -4}}, {{y -> -5}}}
```

This replaces the slot # by each of the entries in the Range. If you want to use a looping construct, you can use

```
Table[Solve[f[x, y] == 0, {y}], {x, 5}]
```

as suggested by March, which gives the same response.